# Change folder picker to a set location

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to change up some code to make this macro more user friendly,if anyone could help that would be great.

Would like to have a set folder always selected rather than the user choosing with the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`

**My code**

```
Sub SearchWKBooks()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim myfolder As String
Dim Str As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheet1

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

Str = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Search string:", Title:="Search all BOM Workbooks", Type:=2)

If Str = "" Then Exit Sub    
WS.Range("A1") = "Search string:"
WS.Range("B1") = Str
WS.Range("A2") = "Path:"
WS.Range("B2") = myfolder
WS.Range("A3") = "Workbook"
WS.Range("B3") = "Worksheet"
WS.Range("C3") = "Cell Address"
WS.Range("D3") = "Link"    
a = 0    
Value = Dir(myfolder)
Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Password protected"
                a = a + 1
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
                For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                        Set c = sht.Cells.Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                            firstAddress = c.Address
                            Do
                                WS.Range("A4").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
                                WS.Range("B4").Offset(a, 0).Value = sht.Name
                                WS.Range("C4").Offset(a, 0).Value = c.Address
                                WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("D4").Offset(a, 0), Address:=myfolder & Value, SubAddress:= _
                                sht.Name & "!" & c.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"
                                a = a + 1
                                Set c = sht.Cells.FindNext(c)
                            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
                        End If
                Next sht
            End If
            Workbooks(Value).Close False
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
    Value = Dir
Loop
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to open a specific folder and be able to select .xlsx or .xls files.
Change the name of the myPath address

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim myPath As String, Fname As String

    myPath = "C:\SourceFolder"

    ChDir myPath
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files, *.xlsx; *.xls", Title:="Select File", MultiSelect:=False)
    If Fname <> fale Then
        Workbooks.Open (Fname)
    End If
End Sub
```